# EF Core DbContext Complex Many To Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have just switched to EFCore from EF6 and I am having trouble coming up with words for my question.

Basically, there is a Many-To-Many relationship that I managed myself in my previous DbContext, but I thought that I would put in some hard yards now and see if I can get EF to work its magic for me.

**Here is the setup**

My application allows for users to create their own objects. The Users create the `ObjectType` and then add `ObjectFields` to the type. Then they can create `Objects` of `ObjectType` (e.g. Term with a field of name and description). Once they have created an `Object`, it can be linked to folders that are in an existing system.

I keep the `Objects` in a table that looks similar to below

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ObjectID |    ObjectFieldID     | Value         |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1      |       1              | Term One Name |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1      |       2              | Term One Desc |
--------------------------------------------------
|   2      |       1              | Term Two Name |
--------------------------------------------------
|   2      |       2              | Term Two Desc |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Here are my classes:

**Object**

```
public class Object
{
    [Key]
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int ObjectFieldID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }


    public virtual ObjectField ObjectField { get; set; }

    //Object's Folders
    public virtual ICollection<FolderObject> FolderObjects { get; set; }
}
```

**Folder**

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public int FolderID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FolderObject> FolderObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am trying to make a Table that will allow me to hold the Many-To-Many relationship, but when a user creates one of their custom objects, it is composed ob multiple `Object`s.

Here is my class for the many to many relationship:

**FolderObject**

```
public class FolderObject
{
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }

    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Object> Object{ get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I am ***ATTEMPTING*** to configure the relationship using the Fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FolderObject>()
            .HasOne<Folder>(fo => fo.Folder)
            .WithMany(f => f.FolderObject)
            .HasForeignKey(fo => fo.FolderID);

///HERE is my issue.... How do I create this relationship?
modelBuilder.Entity<FolderObject>()
            .HasOne<ICollection<Object>>(fo => fo.Object)
            .WithMany();//Error thrown here since the "One" is a Collection
```

This is probably fairly unusual and I can go on managing the Many-To-Many relationship in the same table manually as I was with EF6, but I was hoping that someone out there may have had a similar scenario and found a solution.

All help is appreciated. I can understand that my explanation of my setup could be confusing. Very willing to explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

change `FolderObject` to this :

```
public class FolderObject
{
    public int FolderID { get; set; }
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }

    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public Object Object{ get; set; }
}
```

and change config to this :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<FolderObject>()
        .HasKey(bc => new { bc.FolderID, bc.ObjectID });  

    modelBuilder.Entity<FolderObject>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Folder)
        .WithMany(b => b.FolderObject)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.FolderID);  

    modelBuilder.Entity<FolderObject>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Object)
        .WithMany(c => c.FolderObject)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ObjectID);
```

Comment: `Object` has a composite key, not a principle key, so setting the FK to the `Object.ObjectID` does not work. It seems that setting the FK to a composite key isn't possible when doing many to many?